Linking a Sphinx/RST project to external spreadsheet/database
I'm creating an operations manual for a restaurant using Sphinx and RST, that has entries for various recipes. The recipes are currently in a Google sheet, that is mostly maintained by other people.
I could just copy and paste the info from the spreadsheet into the RST file, but I was hoping for a bit more durable solution. My goal is to keep the manual reliably in sync with the spreadsheet used by kitchen staff. Is there any way to have Sphinx pull the data from the sheet directly, so it stays in sync as others make changes to the spreadsheet? Or, any other data storage solution besides Google sheets that would work more easily with Sphinx?

Well, if this is too personal for your own work, you are supposed to write the glue code (likely in Python) to generate those reStructuredText source files from a spreadsheet. Sphinx itself only focuses on generating documentation, so it doesn't step too far out.

Write a script that connects to the Google API, then downloads the data as a CSV file, which can then be parsed by Sphinx. See https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

https://sphinxcontribdatatemplates.readthedocs.io may helps.
